# Java NullPointerException in Array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I get an error when I do the following operation.

```
public static String text = "ng"; 
public static String[] specialConsonants = new String[4];
public static String[] specialConsonantsUni = new String[6];

public void setSpecial(){
    specialConsonantsUni[0] = "ං";
    specialConsonants[0] = "ng";
    specialConsonantsUni[1] = "ඃ";
    specialConsonants[1] = "h/g";
    specialConsonantsUni[2] = "ඞ";
    specialConsonants[2] = "N/g";
    specialConsonantsUni[3] = "ඍ";
    specialConsonants[3] = "R/g";
    // special characher Repaya
    specialConsonantsUni[4] = "ර්" + "\u200D";
    specialConsonants[4] = "/R/g";
    specialConsonantsUni[5] = "ර්" + "\u200D";
    specialConsonants[5] = "/\\r/g";
}
public static void main(String args[]){

    for (int i=0; i < specialConsonants.length; i++){
        text = text.replace(specialConsonants[i], specialConsonantsUni[i]);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a locale app. So you may not see some fonts. The error is following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.replace(Unknown Source)
at in.isuru.srtuc.Stuff.main(Stuff.java:223)
```

Comment: it appears that you must call your `setSpecial()` method to initialize the values of the array

Answer (score 1):

`specialConsonants` and `specialConsonantsUni` are not initilized. You've just defined `setSpecial()` but not called it before doing replaces

The correct behavior would be:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    setSpecial();
    for (int i=0; i < specialConsonants.length; i++){
        text = text.replace(specialConsonants[i], specialConsonantsUni[i]);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

note also that `setSpecial` should be static in that case

Moreover you have to change dimension of `specialConsonants` to 6

Answer (score 1):

Because specialConsonants[i] is null. You have not initialized it.

its like

```
specialConsonants = {null,null,null,null}
```

You need to make function setSpecial static then call it before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] specialConsonants = new String[4];

public void setSpecial(){
    // ...
    specialConsonants[5] = "/\\r/g";
}
```

`specialConsonants` is of array size 4. There is no 5th index for it. Also you haven't called the array initializer method.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding elements to an already filled array. Array indexes start from 0, When you declared :

```
 public static String[] specialConsonants = new String[4];
```

That means you can only use `specialConsonants[0]` to `specialConsonants[3]`

I suggest you use a **hashmap** for this thing.

```
HashMap<String, String> specialConsonants = new HashMap<String, String>();
....
specialConsonants.put("ං" , "ng" );
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `specialConsonants` as an array of length 4, but you're assigning 6 elements to it.

`specialConsonants[4]` has enough room for elements 0, 1, 2, and 3.
You need to declare it as `specialConsonants[6]` if you want indices 0 - 5.

Then you need to call `setSpecial()` before you use the array in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

the array definition looks wrong, seems you want two same size array but you defined as :

```
public static String[] specialConsonants = new String[4];
public static String[] specialConsonantsUni = new String[6];
```

I think it should be:

```
public static String[] specialConsonants = new String[6];
public static String[] specialConsonantsUni = new String[6];
```